# IIS Problem - Configuration Button Not Responding

Tags: iis, windows-xp

I'm having some trouble with IIS on a Windows XP SP3 machine. When you go into the properties of the Default Website and go to the Home Directory Tab, there's a "Configuration..." Button that when clicked, is supposed to bring up a window where you can define application mappings. The problem I'm having is that when I click the button (which is not disabled) it does nothing. The second dialog box just doesn't come up. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling IIS, even using a Windows XP CD instead of the I386 directory on the PC. I've also tried removing the application, clicking OK, then going back in and trying the "Configuration..." button and it still doesn't work. Any suggestions? I've tried Googling for a few hours now and I haven't found any suggestions other than reinstall IIS (which I've tried) and reinstall the operating system (which is not an option).

[image: Web Site Properties]
<sub>(source: [obsidianspider.com](http://www.obsidianspider.com/vmf/forpost/2009/02/properties.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, this fixed it:

C:\windows\system32> regsvr32.exe atl.dll

C:\windows\system32> regsvr32.exe %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appconf.dll

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and resolved it today by running the following from the command prompt in the C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv directory:
regsvr32 asp.dll

Answer (score 0):

I had this a couple of weeks ago when I was installing everything on a new machine.

The solution was to uninstall and reinstall the .NET framework using the aspnet_regiis.exe utility.

Use -u to uninstall and then -i to reinstall.

Comment: Thanks.  I just tried it by uninstalling .net 1.1 and 2.0 then installing one, the other, then both.  I also tried using the -ua flag to remove everything .net and to install 1.1, then 2.0.  Unfortunately this didn't fix the problem. :(

Comment: I also tried uninstalling .NET completely via Add/Remove Programs, rebooting, then reinstalling .NET.  Everything else seems to be OK, but that stupid "Configuration..." button is still not functioning.